# Xcode 5: UITextView Attributed Text not working in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

As the title says, for some reason setting the attributed text/string of a UITextView directly in the storyboard, is not working.

[image]

Is this a bug? and how would I manage to attribute a long text, then?

Comment: Do you get the same result when running the application?

Comment: Yes, the text is not attributed.

Comment: You can set the attributed text through Storyboard and see the changes real-time.

Comment: Same problem. I was trying to use a custom font. Did you find a solution?